# Can't install PHP on Chef due to conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, provisioning

I'm encountering some problems trying to install PHP on my node on AWS (using as OS Amazon AMI, that is some sort of Red Hat). 
When I try to run chef-solo I receive this output:

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'yum_package[php-mysql]'
================================================================================

Chef::Exceptions::Exec
----------------------
yum -d0 -e0 -y install php-mysql-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1 returned 1:
STDOUT:  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

STDERR: Error: php56-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64

Cookbook Trace:
---------------
/home/ec2-user/chef-repo/localrepo/chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/compat_resource/files/lib/chef_compat/monkeypatches/chef/runner.rb:41:in `run_action'

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /home/ec2-user/chef-repo/localrepo/chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/php/recipes/module_mysql.rb

 22: package node['php']['mysql']['package'] do
 23:   action :install
 24: end

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /home/ec2-user/chef-repo/localrepo/chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/php/recipes/module_mysql.rb:22:in `from_file'

yum_package("php-mysql") do
  package_name "php-mysql"
  action [:install]
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  default_guard_interpreter :default
  declared_type :package
  cookbook_name "php"
  recipe_name "module_mysql"
  flush_cache {:before=>false, :after=>false}
end

Platform:
---------
x86_64-linux
```

That's my repo with cookbooks and config file:

https://github.com/Leonardo610/tirocinio

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is there a Php version already installed on that node? And if yes what is that version?

Comment: the output of "php -v" shows me 5.6.22

Comment: Ok so this happening due to version conflict in your cook book "yum -d0 -e0 -y install php-mysql-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1" it is trying to install php 5.3 and you have php 5.6 So either remove Php 5.6 from the node or edit the version in cook book to 5.6

Comment: I have ran "sudo yum remove php.*" but if I type php -v it continues to work. How do I delete definitely php?

Comment: Use this "sudo apt-get -y purge php.*"

Comment: I haven't apt-get, I'm on Amazon AMI, but I think the meaning of the command (yum or apt-get) is the same.

Comment: Yes that will work

Comment: I have uninstalled all php packages and reinstall them via Chef. I always obtain the same error on php-mysql. "yum info php" returns version 5.3.29 and "php -v" returns 5.6.22. I don't know what to do :S

Comment: Can you tell me the path and name of the cookbook responsible for installing the php-mysql?

Comment: Read your files [here is the problem](https://github.com/Leonardo610/tirocinio/blob/master/cookbooks/php/attributes/default.rb#L67)  It install php56-devel wich depends on php-commons, as you wish version 5.3 and by default it tries to install 5.6  you have a problem of conflict. Looking at your github repo it's quite hard to tell how it really does this that said :/